# Bootstrap dropdown to span 100%

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Im fairly new to web design and have encountered a problem which i cant seem to find a solution for.  Im creating a site and the dropdown menu i want to have is centered and and spans 100% of the screen.  I have the menu working but when i click the dropdown the toggle button also spans to the same width as the actual dropdown menu, causing all the other navigation elements to be pushed to the right.

http://cheekylildevils.co.uk is where you can see what i mean when you click the dropdown menu within the navbar.

Thanks in advance

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
  </div>
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <ul class="nav nav-pills">
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">About Us <b class="caret"></b></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="menu1">
                        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                          <a href="#">More options</a>
                          <a href="#">More options</a>
                          <a href="#">More options</a>
                          <a href="#">More options</a>
                          <a href="#">More options</a>
                          <a href="#">More options</a>
                        </li>
                  </ul>
            </li>
     </ul>
    <li><a href="#">Key Info</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Learning</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Children</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul> 
</div>
</nav>
```

Css:

```
.nav {
    display: inline-block;
}
.navbar-header {
    float: none;
}
.navbar-left,.navbar-right {
    float: none !important;
}
.navbar-toggle {
    display: block;
}
.navbar .navbar-nav {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.navbar-collapse {
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    text-align: center;
}
.navbar-fixed-top {
    top: 0;
    border-width: 0 0 1px;
}
.nav-pills>li {
    float: none;
}
.nav-pills>li>a {
    color: #fff;
}
.nav-pills>li>a:hover {
    background: none;
}
.nav .open>a, .nav .open>a:hover {
    background: none!important;
    border: none!important;
}
.navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: none!important;
    background-color: rgba(3, 3, 3, 0.63);      
}
.navbar-nav {
    float: none!important;
    margin-top: 0px;
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.navbar-nav>li {
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
}
.navbar-nav>li>a {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.collapse.in{
    display:block !important;
}
.navbar-inverse {
    background-color: #c31f40;
    border-color: #d82a4d;
}
.open>.dropdown-menu {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    position: static;
    background: none;
    color: #fff;
}
.dropdown-menu>li>a {
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Please do not use "bootstrap" tag, use "twitter-bootstrap" since it means something else

Comment: Please post your code and images for us to solve. Quick, before someone downvotes you :D

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. As Daniel said, show us what you've tried. Post the code you are using. This community will help you correct your code or find the mistakes in it. It will not do the full job you.

Comment: Sorry about that, hopefully thats the post sorted now

Comment: ive tried to resize each elent but it seems the button and the dropdown are contained in the same div so gives me bad results when i do any resizing.